# gnuplot draw two plots on the same graph with single column data

Tags: gnuplot

There are two data files, say **data1.txt**:

```
31231
32312
32323
32323
```

**data2.txt**:

```
32323
54223
32456
45321
```

I want to draw the two plots on the same graph, how can I use `gnuplot` to realize that? Thank yu very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could get two plots on the same graph in one `plot` command with two `datafile` arguments, separated by a comma. For instance

```
  plot [-1:5] 'data1.txt' with points, 'data2.txt' with points
```

would get you something like this:

[image]

Comment: how do I draw with lines? I tried `plot 'data1', 'data2' with lines`, but I got all points and the points are all on the 0 x-axis.

Comment: with lines applies only to the second datafile. Try `plot 'data1' with lines, 'data2' with lines`. It looks like `gnuplot` is unable to find file `data2` in the same directory.

Comment: I also tried `plot 'data1', 'data2' with points` but couldn't get what you got. All the points are on the 0 x-axis, why's that?

Comment: it could be either that the scale on the y-axis is wrong or that gnuplot cannot read the right 'data1' file.

Comment: If you are on linux, you could type gnuplot command `! cat data1` to see the contents of the file.

Comment: @user1224398 if this worked for you, feel free to accept this answer ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work ) ... It looks like a good answer to me. +1

Answer (score 1):

This works for me :

```
reset 
set term pngcairo
set output 'wall.png'
set xlabel "Length (meter)"
set ylabel "error (meter)"
set style line 1 lt 1 linecolor rgb "yellow" lw 10 pt 1
set style line 2 lt 1 linecolor rgb "green" lw 10 pt 1
set style line 3 lt 1 linecolor rgb "blue" lw 10 pt 1
set datafile separator ","
set key
set auto x
set xtics 1, 2, 9
set yrange [2:7]
set grid

set label "(Disabled)" at -.8, 1.8
plot  "file1.csv" using 1:2 ls 1 title "one" with lines ,\
  "file2.csv" using 1:2 ls 2 title "two" with lines ,\
  "file3.csv" using 1:2 ls 3 title "three" with lines
set output
```